# react-navigation how to nest TapNavigator inside createAppContainer

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

Hi I am trying to nest `createMaterialTopTabNavigator` inside `createAppContainer` but give me an error that I have `duplicate declaration App` below is my code:

```
import { createAppContainer, createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs';

export default class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
        <AppTabNavigator/>
      </SafeAreaView>
    )
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <Text>HomeScreen</Text>
      </View>
      )
  }
}

class SettingsScreen extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <Text>SettingsScreen</Text>
      </View>
      )
  }
}

const AppTabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
  Home:{screen:HomeScreen},
  Settings:{ screen: SettingsScreen}
  })

const App = createAppContainer(AppTabNavigator)
```

This will give me an error that I have duplicate `App`. Any ideas why?
Any advice or comments would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I made a silly mistake. It should have been like this:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
        <AppContainer />
      </SafeAreaView>
    )
  }
}

const AppTabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
  Home:{screen:HomeScreen},
  Settings:{ screen: SettingsScreen}
  })

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppTabNavigator)
```